# JavaFX Stage.close() not calling my onCloseRequest() handler

Tags: javafx

Please refer to the JavaFX SSCCE below. The print statement appears when closing the primary stage from the window's default titlebar "X" button. The print statement does NOT appear when clicking the "Close" button. Why isn't my onCloseHandler being called when I call close() on the stage? Is my expectation somehow unreasonable or is this (yet another) bug in JavaFX? Thanks!

```
public class Main extends Application { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }   
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {     
        Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
        closeButton.setOnAction(e -> {          
            primaryStage.close();
        });     
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            System.out.println("onCloseRequest handler called!");
        });
        StackPane rootPane = new StackPane();
        rootPane.getChildren().add(closeButton);        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootPane, 300, 250));       
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It only works for ***external*** close requests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described by the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onCloseRequestProperty), this is only fired on *external* requests:

> Called when there is an external request to close this Window.

Maybe `setOnHidden` would work for you, it is called in both cases.

```
public class Main extends Application { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }   
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {     
        Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
        closeButton.setOnAction(e -> {          
            primaryStage.close();
        });     
        primaryStage.setOnHidden(e -> {
            System.out.println("stage hidden");
        });
        StackPane rootPane = new StackPane();
        rootPane.getChildren().add(closeButton);        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootPane, 300, 250));       
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Listening for onHidden works, thanks! I think I may never understand why a stage's own title bar X button issues an "external" close, nor why the JDK should even try to make such a distinction in the first place. It boggles my mind what Oracle is thinking with JavaFX sometimes.

Comment: @BinaryDigit09 It's "external" because it's a native OS request to close the window, instead of a call from Java code. The window itself is generated from the native windowing toolkit and the "decoration" buttons (such as the close button) are provided by the native kit. Thus if the user presses the close button, the OS requests to close the window (same is true if you close from a task bar action, etc.).

Comment: @BinaryDigit09 The distinction is sometimes helpful: if you want to veto a close (save changes? yes/no/cancel) etc, you don't need a handler to do that if you're closing the window from your own code (because you just display the dialog and then decide whether or not to call `hide()`). But if you want to do that when the user presses the native "close" button, etc, you need a handler to catch that action. Note that `onHidden` is invoked when the window is actually closed: you can't veto a close request from there.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the reply. I think I understand better now what they mean by an "external" close request, and the differences between close() and hide(). I'm so used to Swing that I assumed hide() would leave resources behind, similar to calling setVisible(false) instead of dispose() on a Swing window.